# Perform Click in other form without using the new form object C#

Tags: c#

I have here the public void in my first form

```
  public void newtransac()
  {
   button50.PerformClick();
   }
```

then in my second form, i want to call the function of my first form
without showing restaurantSale form.

```
  restaurantSale transac = null;
  transac.newtransac();
  transac.Show();
```

Thanks..then how to do it but not showing the restaurantSale form
the error that i have Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: If you set transac to null then you do not have an object to call newtransac() on. That is what the error says. Try restaurantSale transac = new restaurantSale(). If this does not work, you have to provide more context...

Comment: can  you help me for that. how it works?

Comment: I am sorry, but if you cannot replace some text by some other text you are going to have some learning curve before you. No offence.

Comment: @oliver what do you mean?

Comment: You are not ready to solve this problem yet. Start with a lot simpler problems first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use controls in your form without showing the form at least one time also added to having use the same instance that you used before.

**Example**, you can define the form in **Program.cs** file as following

```
public static resturantSale transac;
```

and inside the **Main()**

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    transac = new resturantSale();
    Application.Run(transac);
}
```

this line `Application.Run(transac);` let you start the program with this form, you can use `transac.Show();` every time you want to form be visible, without making a new instance.

Also if you call it from **outside** the file **Program.cs**, you have to use it like this

`Program.transac.Show();`

After you accomplished this stage, you can call this method `Program.transac.newtransac();`, but be careful when you using it in **static** or **non-static** methods.

I hope my answer is worked for you.